# How to invert element position with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Bit of an old problem here, I've read over 20 various articles and have been reminded about how hard this is. If there's an answer, please post or point me toward it.

Here's a fiddle of what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/6xuSp/

Requirements:

- Vertical centered content boxes (`left` and `right`)
- Left declared element to be displayed on the right
- No heights declared (either content box could have variable contents, and yes I declared a height on a content box in the above fiddle, just to show the centering)
- No Javascript
- All major browsers supported (IE8+, 7 nicely displaying is ideal, 6 is not an issue)

The above fiddle pretty much does what I want, except the inversion of the 2 content boxes. I have invalidated the float attributes, as they cancel the vertical alignment. I don't mind if we use floats (or another CSS technique), so long as we can meet the above requirements.

cheers,
d

Comment: Curious as to why they have to be inverted...?

Comment: When the browser is reduced, "right" content box should be on top of "left" content box.

Comment: Did you try using `direction`?

Comment: Interesting, @Truth, how to pull "left" over to the left now, when I have rtl on the wrapper?

Comment: It's problematic without using media queries or Javascript. If you had one of those this would have been a breeze.

Comment: Indeed, I might propose that the inversion be a progressive enhancement with JS. I figured this would be difficult :/ Thanks Truth.

Comment: Go ahead and add that as an answer if you like Truth, in the end I switched to display:inline-block; & direction:rtl; and it almost fits the bill (though not quite - I want 'right' to be right aligned, and 'left' left aligned, as the elements would with floating).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYyjb/)

Comment: No, neither 'left' nor 'right' boxes are vertically centered within 'wrap'. I may not have been clear enough - both content boxes must be vertically centered within 'wrap', as the 'wrap' height expands from either content box.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fiddle does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xuSp/37/

Instead of inverting the order, I've used `z-index` to put the right box on top.

Comment: Pete and Truth: sorry peeps jsfiddle seems to be broken; I'll have to check back later.

Comment: As mentioned in the solution - they don't need to be inverted if all you're worried about is the right box appearing over the top of the left, you can use `z-index` to achieve the same effect.